# dynamically loading a dylib (Objective-c) in a swift project

Tags: swift, objective-c, dylib

I created a dylib in Objective-c with
myLib.h

```
 #import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface myLib : NSObject
{
    int value;

}
-(void)print;
-(void)setValue:(int)val;
-(int)getValue;
@end
```

and myLib.m

```
#import "myLib.h"

@implementation myLib

-(void)print {
    NSLog(@"Printed from myLib");
}
-(void)setValue:(int)val {
     value = val;
}
-(int)getValue {
     return value;
}
@end
```

and tried to load it dynamically on another command line app

```
@class myLib;
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {
    @autoreleasepool {
        
        void *handle = dlopen("libmyLib.dylib", RTLD_LAZY);
    
        //method - 1
        id t = [[NSClassFromString(@"myLib") alloc] init];
        myLib *libObj = [[t alloc] init];
        [libObj print];  // Error: Receiver type 'myLib' for instance message is a forward declaration
        
        
        //method - 2
        Class class = (__bridge Class)(dlsym(handle, "OBJC_CLASS_$_myLib"));
        if(class){
            myLib *libObj = [[class alloc] init];
            [libObj print];        // Error: Receiver type 'myLib' for instance message is a forward declaration
            [libObj setValue:5];  // Error: Receiver type 'myLib' for instance message is a forward declaration
            [libObj getValue]    // Error: Receiver type 'myLib' for instance message is a forward declaration
        }
        dlclose(handle);
    }
    return 0;
}
```

got some errors, and also dlopen fails , can anyone figure out the problem with this code.

Can we use swift code instead of Objective-c for dylib, if so how can we call the functions inside the dylib.

Comment: You might find [this discussion](https://forums.swift.org/t/swift-shared-libraries-as-plugins/20319) useful.   Can you not use `NSBundle`? (or `Bundle` in Swift?).

Comment: On the ObjC side have you tried importing "myLib.h" in the file containing the definition of `main`?

Comment: Why do you even need this? Why not just configure it via the project (there are a few options there: embed it, mark it required, load it based on build target, etc)?

Comment: I need to call the methods of dylib only if the dylib is present in a particular location.